# suggestions for a generic report engine

Tags: java, xml, templates, report

I want to build a generic report engine which uses templates for customization. For data input, I get a JSON and the output should be PDF. More specific, I report historical data from a project management tool. E.g. How the tasks performed and which status flag they have.

So far, I have built three projects with different libraries, as a proof of concept:

1. iText v7.1, which works nice, but the template options were limited
2. Jasper Reports v6.12, which uses a proprietary format for the templates and also would require the .jrxml editor
3. working with Apache POI and docx4j v6.1 to use Microsoft Word for customizing the templates

I like the idea of the last program, but more than often I get corrupted pdfs after changing the templates. So, it works quite unstable and I am afraid the client will break it within the first days.

I am required to find a way of customizing the templates without having the client to install an additional program like a WYSIWYG editor.

My questions are:

1. Is there a library that I'm missing so far?
2. Should I reject the idea that the client should have the possibility to edit the template himself?

If you need a general overview of the architectures, I used in the three projects, I will pass them!

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid that this is likely to be closed on the grounds that questions seeking advice on technology selection are out of scope. There's a good reason for that, which is that you really need to spend more than 5 minutes studying a problem before leaping to conclusions about the right design approach. But I'm going to answer anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will keep this in mind in the future.
Is it legitimate to ask for library recommendations in a smaller scale?

Answer (score 0):

Consider XSLT 3.0 feeding into either XSL-FO or css-print for the PDF generation.

XSLT is generally as good as any custom report writer for structuring reports. It lacks some of the high-level primitives like rolling over subtotals from one page to the next, but my experience is that those are often not needed anyway. XSLT 3.0 is quite capable of handling JSON as well as XML input.

For the output formatting side css-print is probably a more modern approach than XSL-FO but a lot depends on how much detailed control you want over the pixel-level quality of the printed page.

Comment: Thank you for your time, answering a not well defined question. Just to illustrate my understanding, I will go through the main parts of the report component again.

Comment: I will parse the json file with the XSLT library and also model my report template with it. Since the report engine should work not only with a specific input, there will be no pojo class for representation of the parsed json object. At this point, I used simple string replacements to fill out the placeholders in the template with the parsed information.

Comment: As far as the pdf export is concerned, I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by css print.
Moreover, does this mean that the template can not be customized within the process?

To meet the needs of the program, I must provide some kind of editability to the templates. E.g every client has his own idea of which information he wants to display in the report and which charts he needs. In most cases a logo must also be added.